# it means a lot to me

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **Their recovery times have been impressive, and hardly any of them have been classified as "agitated," even before fourth donation**. Okay, maybe I am boasting now. But **it** means a lot to me, **being able to do my work well**, especially that bit about my donors

[Source](https://www.npr.org/2005/05/04/4629918/kazuo-ishiguro-never-let-me-go)

---

I wonder if "**it**" refers to "**their recovery**..." or "**being able to**...".

Comment: It's all a bit vague, but *syntactically*, "it" appears to refer to ***being able to do my work well***. Which logically may not make much sense, but that's just how people speak in relaxed informal contexts. Obviously in the real world what means a lot to the speaker is that the people he treats recover quickly.

Comment: It means a lot to me, not being burned alive, which is why I keep matches and gasoline apart from each other.

Comment: Well, I suppose *maybe* all the speaker cares about is the fact that he's good at his job (those favourable patient outcomes are just *evidence* of his skill, not something he cares about *for their own sake*). After all, he does admit he's "boasting".